# Issue with aligning elements: why doesn't align-items:center work

Tags: html, css, sass

**Why doesn't** `align-items:center` **work?**
If I use `padding: 40px 0;` it works. but how do I get the result. that the `height` would be centered?
in my case, it's just pressed to the top.

```css
.header { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
.container {
 max-width: 1280px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.center-align {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}


a, span {
color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="center-align">
        <div class="header-logo"><a href="#!">logo</a></div>
        <div class="header-mmm"><span>test</span></div>
        <div class="header-buttons">
        <button>test</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.center-align` div is only as tall as its contents. If you set its parent to `display:flex`, the `.center-align` div would then fill the height of the `header` and you'd see your elements vertically aligned. Or you could just set the height instead on the `.center-align` div.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use padding with your display flex.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.center {
  padding: 70px 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="center">
  <p>I am vertically and horizontally centered.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This way you can adjust how high/low your text ist supposed to be.
Hope I could help!

Philipp